# How to merge graphQL fragments for request with apollo client

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have the following types and:

```
union U = B|C|D

type A = { childs: U }
```

that I use with this fragment which works fine and apollo client is able to resolve child objects correctly

```
fragment A on A {
    childs {
        ...B
        ...C
        ...D
    }
}
```

when I convert this into

```
fragment A on A {
    childs {
        U
    }
}

fragment U on U {
    ...B
    ...C
    ...D
}
```

the apollo client is not able to resolve the childs anymore, all objects are empty without any fields. Is there any way to merge the fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think there might be a typo in your conversion? The U has missing `...`

```
fragment A on A {
    childs {
        ...U # here
    }
}
```

I think you should also try to use [conditional fragments](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types)

```
fragment U on U {
    ... on B {
        ...B
    }
    ... on C {
        ...C
    }
    ... on D {
        ...D
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result as with my query, the query works, but the items in the apollo store are empty, with no fields

Comment: Sorry don't really know what is wrong. Maybe you can check your `dataIdFromObject ` is working fine, and make sure your fragments always query the id field. Maybe you can include the output of this query + the state of the Apollo store before/after the query in your question

Comment: What could be the problem with `dataIdFromObject`

Comment: if it always returns the same value, the result of one type may override the result of another type. This can be seen if you post the state of your apollo store.

Comment: Found the problem, I missed the resolver for the union type.